# Displaying the Coordinates of on the Google Map through Marker

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to locate coordinates on the Google maps.

I have the ID and the coordinates from the JSON

I have a Coordinates from the JSON Which are coming like

coordinates =[-12.9487,9.0131]

I want to show them on google maps through marker..

Can anyone tell me how to show it

we have in google maps
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);

but they are different values not an array. how to display my JSon coordinates [-12.9487,9.0131] on google map through marker.

Comment: What order are the numbers in the coordinates array?  Are they `[latitude, longitude]` or `[longitude, latitude]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var coordinates =[-12.9487,9.0131];
```

would be either (`[latitude, longitude]`):

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng([coordinates[0],coordinates[1]);
```

or (`[longitude,latitude]`):

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng([coordinates[1],coordinates[0]);
```

I'm going to assume the second, because the first is in the middle of the ocean.

```js
var coordinates = [-12.9487, 9.0131];

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0]);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map
  })

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```